# Unable to rewrite multiple URL rewrite with same paramters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Need your expert help. I am trying to rewrite 2 url's in htaccess where both url's have same parameters. After rewriting url only 1st url rewrite is working. Can anybody help me on how to make both url rewrite work?

Here is my htaccess code code.

```
1st URL : http://www.example.com/quotaid.php?id=id/address
which i want to rewrite to
http://www.example.com/id/address
//1st URL rewrite
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/([a-zA-Z0-9]+|[0-9a-zA-Z]+)/?$
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+|[0-9a-zA-Z]+)/(.*)$ quotaid.php?id=$1 [NC,L]

2nd URL : http://www.example.com/zipquota.php?zip=zip/address
which i want to rewrite to
http://www.example.com/zip/address
//2nd URL rewite in htaccess
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ zipquota.php?zip=$1 [NC,L]
```

Only one url rewrite is working which comes first. If i move the 2nd url rewrite to top, then the 2nd url rewrite is working but the 1st url stops working. PLease help on how to manage both url rewrite working.

Comment: This is a bit unclear... `http://www.example.com/quotaid.php?id=id/address` is _not_ a valid URL, that slash between `id` and ` address` would have to be encoded. So the question is: what should be the internal URL getting called?

Comment: Please read the code as http://www.example.com/quotaid.php?id=$id where $id = id/address

Comment: Also something like this makes no sense: `([a-zA-Z0-9]+|[0-9a-zA-Z]+)`, both patterns are identical. You may want to use `([a-z0-9]+)` in combination with the `NC` flag (no case).

Comment: Please edit your question and make clear what is code, what _exactly_ you want, so that the question can be answered.

Comment: The reason why only one rule gets applied is obvious: your condition and rule pattern match both times, so it is always the first one getting tried, matched and applied.

Comment: Thats precisely my point is. I am looking for any alternative to get this work. Please suggest.

Comment: When i run the URL rewrite, it runs only 1st url rewrite and ignores 2nd url rewrite. If i move the 2nd URL rewrite to top, then it starts working but the other stops working. I dont know on how more i can elaborate the issue.

Comment: I did not say that the pattern `([a-zA-Z0-9]+|[0-9a-zA-Z]+)` does not work. I said it makes zero sense. You did not understand how regular expressions work. The order you specify characters in a set has absolutely no meaning.

Comment: ooh ok. I understood. I will change accordingly.
also please suggest an alternative for this issue as i want both url work

Comment: And once more the reason why only the first rule gets applied: you have no distinction between the two URLs, as far as I can tell. COnsequently both conditions and patterns are more or less identical. But how should a difference get applied in that case?

Comment: So the question is: how do boths URLs actually differ?

Comment: Please give a _specific_ example without using placeholders.

Comment: Yes. That is my issue. So can you please suggest what to do to make differ in between?

Comment: No, I cannot suggest how your URLs look like, you have to know. So please: an example from your site...

Comment: So what i understood is that there is no alternative to rewrite multiple url's with same pattern. If that is the case, i need to work on changing the pattern to make it different. Thanks for your support.

Comment: Yep, correct. Since there is no way to differ between them, how should the server differ between them?

Comment: That is why I asked for an example. It might be that there _is_ some pattern to differ, for example by what pattern `id` and `zip` can take. But you have to tell us...

Comment: ooh ok. pls wait let me share examples

Comment: OK, giving up. Have fun!

Comment: nono not giving up. i though this is end of the story. i didnt expect your reply :-(

Comment: I would like to help and answer, but you need to answer to questions. So: how do `id` and `zip` differ in their pattern? And what does `address` contain? Please add specific examples to your question.

Comment: Sure give me a moment. i am working on the same.

Comment: The first url looks like this after url rewrite
https://www.example.com/CV17057071/3677-Louise-Street-Lynwood-CA-90262
and the 2nd URL looks like 
https://www.example.com/propbyzip=?91007/HOMES-FOR-Arcadia-CA

Comment: Actual url for the 1st link provided was example.com/listid=?CV17057071/3677-Louise-Street-Lynwood-CA-90262

Comment: Once more: please add such details to the question, not in comments.

Comment: And that second example does not really make sense. It does not match what you wrote in your question.

Comment: Do you really need those address parts internally? Typically a script would only need a unique `id` or a `zip` code to operate. I would expect the address only to be there for SEO purposes.

Comment: I do agree but this is the client requirement. :-( and exactly it is for SEO purpose only.

Comment: As initially set: a slash in the URL at that position is invalid. So what should be done? Is the address part _internally_ required at all? I would expect it to be ignored by the script anyway. If it is required, then probably something like `...?id=<id>&address=<address>` makes sense. Or it has to be encoded: `...?id=<id>%2F<address>` But _you_ have to tell what.

Comment: agree to that point. I had made this as <id>.'/'.<address> in code to avoid of str_replace(). So if i use <id>&address=<address> what url rewrite can be.

Comment: here i need to pass multiple parameter in url i believe. Please suggest if i am wrong.

Comment: "I believe" is nothing I like to see in a description of what has to be coded. Coding is not about believing or guessing. You need to know what is required, or you have to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *assume* this is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?([0-9]+)/(.+)$ /zipquota.php?zip=$1&address=$2 [NC,END]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?([0-9a-z]+)/(.+)$ /quotaid.php?id=$1&address=$2 [NC,END]
```

These are the internal rewritings applied by that, as specified by you in the comments to the question, though I dare say that the `address` argument makes zero sense and probably will get removed in future...:

- `https://example.org/91007/HOMES-FOR-Arcadia-CA` => `/zipquota.php?zip=91007&address=HOMES-FOR-Arcadia-CA`
- `https://example.org/CV17057071/3677-Louise-Street-Lynwood-CA-90262` => `/quotaid.php?id=CV17057071&address=3677-Louise-Street-Lynwood-CA-90262`

Those rules should work in the http servers host configuration and likewise in dynamic configuration files (`.htaccess`). To be able to use them in a dynamic configuration file some preconditions have to be matched: the interpretation of such files has to be enabled in the http servers configuration (`AllowOverride ...`), the file has to be readable by the http server and it has to be placed inside the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder configured for that http host.

The `zip` based URLs are rewritten first, since they use a more specific pattern, purely number based. Then comes the more general rule for `id`s with alphanumeric patterns. The condition you originally had does not really make sense, I removed it.

*Note*: I also took the liberty to make those target paths absolute (leading slash) to make the setup more robust. That obviously requires those scripts to be located directly inside the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder. otherwise the paths have to be adjusted.

*Warning*: In case you get a http status 500 (internal server error), chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. In that case you have to replace the `END` flag with the `L` flag. You can see a hint on that in your http servers error log file in that case. The `L` flag *should* work too, unless you have more rewriting rules that might create a conflict.

---

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Thanks for taking so much time and making me understand and trying to solve the issue. But no luck :-(

Here is the code placed in my htaccess.

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?([0-9]+)/(.+)$ /propbyzipcode.php?zip=$1&address=$2 [NC,END]

and below is my url actual one which is not working
https://www.mayvnre.com/91007/HOMES-FOR-Arcadia-CA

Unable to understand what went wrong now.

Comment: And "no luck" or "is not working" means _what_ exactly? What do you see in your http servers error log file? What result do you get?

Comment: Is the interpretation of dynamic configuration files enabled at all? WHere is that file located? How is it called?

Comment: Yes dynamic configuration enabled and working on other url rewrites very well. 

See this example basis our discussion. This is the actual URL now.
https://www.mayvnre.com/propbyzipcode.php?zip=91007&add=HOMES-FOR-Arcadia-CA
which i want to convert to 
https://www.mayvnre.com/91007/HOMES-FOR-Arcadia-CA

But this is not working.I would not be able to discribe much technically since i am novice in htaccess and url rewrite. Hence i had provided actual url for your ready reference and also htaccess code.

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?([0-9]+)/(.+)$ /propbyzipcode.php?zip=$1&add=$2 [NC,END]

Comment: Repeating things does not help, sorry. You need to answer questions. So: what entries do you get in your http servers error log file. I ask that for the third time now...

Comment: There are no entries in server error log file. Its empty.

Comment: Sorry, but that is impossible. An apache error log file _never_ is empty. What file do you refer to?

Comment: i am referring to error_log which is in my server alongside with .htaccess

Comment: Then test your setup: change the `.htaccess` file to contain a definite syntax error, something like `this is an error!` at the top, then make any request, look into your error log file. Do you see an entry?

Comment: Wait... "error_log which is in my server alongside with .htaccess "? A log file does NOT belong into your folder of published documents. Something is fishy here...

Comment: Its crazy. I did a syntax error and checked but no error is showing up :-(
Please refer to the error here: https://www.mayvnre.com/Antelope-CA

How come it is possible? :-(

Comment: That log file is not your http servers error log file. I already said that it is impossible to be empty. Consult your http servers host configuration for the exact location of the correct error log file.

Comment: Ok. I shall get back to you shortly. I will check with my cpanel. It may be available there. Thanks for your time. I shall get back shortly

Comment: Hi. Thanks a ton. It started working now with the code provided by you. Really appreciate your time and efforts.

Comment: Glad to hear that! Would you mind to share what that last issue was in your setup? Just in case others stumble over something similar? Thanks!

Comment: a small correction done to the code provided and started working. Here is the code for your reference:

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/(.+)$ propbyzipcode.php?zip=$1&add=1 [NC,L].

Comment: You removed the leading slash from the target so if that is required that script is not in the location of the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` and also the `.htaccess` file is not. You never mentioned that, though... And you changed the `END` flag for the `L` flag, so most likely just as hinted in the answer you received a http status 500, yet you did not mention that too... Also you certainly did get an entry in your http servers error log file in that case too...

Comment: May be i may not mentioned these points because, i am not aware of these technical terms and agree to my mistakes. Also as far as the error_log data is concerned, i still did not receive any response from my client and chances are there that my client haven't checked yet my message i believe. I am relatively very new to url rewrite and am still under learning process. So i can understand the trouble you gone through in understanding my issues and in resolving them. :-)

Comment: All fine, do not take my words in a wrong way. I am just trying to show the issues that make helping you far more difficult than necessary. It is meant in a constructive way, though indeed I criticize ;-) One hint for your future: if you want to earn money with that line of work you definitely need to create local development environments where you test things before deployihng them online. _There is no way around that_ and you will see that it is far easier then expected at first. And in the end it will save you a lot of time ans hassle. Take care and have fun!

Comment: Thank you so much for your support and guidence. I will surely follow the same and will try to create lde's. will try to get more knowledge and info on this. One thing I have to admit: You are the only one till now i experienced who had gone a long way to help even though you have trouble in understanding my concern technically. Many thanks. Have a nice day.

Comment: seems you are supporting jquery as well as i am stuck with some issue in jquery as well. If possible, please suggest the changes for jquery/php issue which i raised in this fourm.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42896552/post-in-working-in-localhost-but-not-working-on-live-server-php-seems-json-p?noredirect=1#comment72943683_42896552